# Activiti Designer alternative

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn, business-process-management

I'm trying out Activiti to see if we can replace our current approval flow engine with it. I have 2 questions:

1) For all Activiti projects out there deployed on production: is it a hardcoded fact that business/end users are supposed to make new business processes only using Activiti designer (following BPMN 2.0 specification)?

2) Is there a way that we can create a simple facade UI (a UI layer above Activiti designer) that can be easily used by business users to create business processes in terms of business entities they understand & then code wise we try to transform such custom process to standard Activity/BPMN 2.0 XML? This would thus not impose the need for the end users to learn BPMN 2.0 specification (if they need to consistently make new business definitions/processes on run time). I'm not sure if it's feasible?

Comment: You can try out the camunda modeler. https://camunda.org/bpmn/tool/ Also it is possible to migrate from activiti to the camunda process engine.https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/update/activiti/

Comment: Is it open source/free to use on production?

Comment: Yes it is open source. The source is located on github.

Comment: https://bpmn.io is good solution too.

Comment: Is it open source/free to use on production?